# php/mysql Pagination argument not valid

Tags: pagination

After db connection-

```
`$tbl_name="mytable";`
 $adjacents = 3;
 $query = "SELECT COUNT (*) as num FROM $mytable";
 $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));  this is line 32
 $total_pages = $total_pages[num];
 $targetpage = "pagination.php";  (the name of this file)
 $limit = 20;
```

error i am getting is-

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in line 32.

can anyone help?

thanks

Comment: Looks like you are calling the wrong table name: SELECT COUNT (*) as num FROM $tbl_name

Answer (score 1):

The problem should be in your query, it should be either:

```
 $query = "SELECT COUNT (*) as num FROM mytable";
```

or

```
 $query = "SELECT COUNT (*) as num FROM ".$tbl_name."";
```

You are referencing a variable $mytable that you haven't previously defined

Comment: Have you tried your query in phpmyadmin or on the mysql client? Does it return anything? Use mysql_error() to see what the actual problem is otherwise, look at the php docs for this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php